# MeteorJS send files

Tags: meteor, sockjs, http-status-code-413

I need to send an audio to the meteor server, but I keep getting a **413 (Request Entity Too Large)**

I'm using a FileReader to read a file as a binary string and then send it to the server

```
const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
  reader.onload = function(fileLoadEvent) {
    Meteor.call('Action.upload',
    {
      file,
      data: reader.result,
      lang
    },
    (err,res) => {
      console.log(err, res);
    });
   };
```

Comment: Are you using a reverse proxy with nginx, apache, etc? If so, [this might help](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2328/413-request-entity-too-large-error-with-uploading-a-file).

Comment: @Adam No, I don't

Comment: Hmmm... well, I think the concept is the same. We need to increase the max file / body size. Not sure exactly how to do that in meteor. [Maybe this will point you in the right direction...](https://forums.meteor.com/t/request-too-large-body-empty-when-increasing-limit/15925) Also, streaming the data might be possible. This article talks about [server to client streaming, but maybe it would be useful.](https://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-to-streams/)